# VBScript to send email via SMTP

Tags: email, vbscript, smtp

I have the following code, my goal is to send automatic emails to a list of people in an excel document, using a text file as a template:

```
Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
Set app = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("F:\Billing_Common\autoemail").Files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f)) = "xls" Then
    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(f.Path)

set sh = wb.Sheets("Auto Email Script")
row = 2
email = sh.Range("A" & row)
subject = "Billing"
LastRow = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For r = row to LastRow
    If App.WorkSheetFunction.CountA(sh.Rows(r)) <> 0 Then 
    objMessage.Subject = "Billing: Meter Read" 
    objMessage.From = "billing@energia.ie" 
    objMessage.To = email

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim emailText                                   
Set emailText = fso.OpenTextFile("F:\Billing_Common\autoemail\Script\Email.txt", ForReading)                                        
BodyText = emailText.ReadAll

    objMessage.TextBody = emailText

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = CdoSendUsingPort


'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "ADDRESS OF SERVER HERE"

'Server port
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
objMessage.Send

    End if
Next

emailText.Close
Set emailText = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
wb.Close
End If
Next
```

It throws an error at the objMessage.TextBody, saying type mismatch. If anyone could help me it would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I have it working now, but cannot get it to use the text file as a template.

Comment: Scrap that all is working now, but does anyone know how to add an image to it?

Comment: As an attachment? Or do you want to compose HTML mail?

Comment: I think it would have to be HTML mail as it needs to be in the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sending inline images you need to create an `HTMLBody` instead of a `TextBody` and add a `RelatedBodyPart` with the image (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa487614%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx)):

```
Set msg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
...
msg.HTMLBody = "<html>" & vbLf & _
               "<head><title>Test</title></head>" & vbLf & _
               "<body><p><img src='foo.jpg'></p></body>" & vbLf & _
               "</html>"
msg.AddRelatedBodyPart "C:\path\to\your.jpg", "foo.jpg", 0
```

Answer (score 0):

After the line `BodyText = emailText.ReadAll`, you ought to assign *that*, and not the file ("emailText" is the `TextFile` that was `Open`ed by `fso` on the previous line), that's why it's complaining about a Type Mismatch...

So just replace `objMessage.TextBody = emailText` with `objMessage.TextBody = BodyText` and it should work...